# Save value of custom field in minicart to order Magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, mini-cart, custom-field

I have added one field "Special instructions" (textarea) in mini cart which I want to get saved in order details when customer put the order.

In which observer can I get the value of this field? and how can I save it to order?

Answer (score 0):

First, to **add custom field** in quote and order table and *save your data into quote table*.

after creating file **Vendor\Extension\etc\events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
        <observer name="custome" instance="Vendor\Extension\Observer\Custome"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

after creating another file **Vendor\Extension\Observer\Custome.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Customeimplements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_objectManager;

    public function __construct( \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager )
    {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
    }

    public function execute( EventObserver $observer )
    {
        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        $quoteRepository = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository');
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $quoteRepository->get($order->getQuoteId());
        $order->setCustomFiled($quote->getCustomFiled());      
        return $this;
    }
}
```

This code working for me.
Happy Coding..

Comment: Please tell me my solution is working or not.